# Pan sharpening Landsat 8 composites in Google Earth Engine (Python API)

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, google-earth-engine-python-api, pansharpening

I am currently trying to use pan sharpening on Landsat 8 composites with Google Earth Engine. What I did is simply create a composite from an image collection as described in the documentation:

```
collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1').filterDate('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31')
custom_composite = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite(collection=collection,
                                                             percentile=75,
                                                             cloudScoreRange=5)

map_sharpened = folium.Map(location=[37.76664, -122.44829], zoom_start=13)


map_sharpened.add_ee_layer(custom_composite, {
    'bands': ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], 'max': 128, 'gamma': [1.1, 1.1, 1]}, 'rgb')
display(map_sharpened)
```

This works as expected. Next, I want to use pan sharpening on my composite. I am basically following the example in the Earth Engine documentation (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_transforms) with the exception that I use a composite instead of one specific image. However, when I try to display the new layer, I only get a white map.

```
hsv = custom_composite.select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2']).rgbToHsv()
sharpened = ee.Image.cat(
    [hsv.select('hue'),
     hsv.select('saturation'),
     custom_composite.select('B8')]).hsvToRgb()

map_sharpened.add_ee_layer(sharpened, {
    'min': 0, 'max': 0.25, 'gamma': [1.3, 1.3, 1.3]}, 'pan-sharpened')
map_sharpened.add_child(folium.LayerControl())
map_sharpened
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rgbtohsv` and `hsvtorgb` expect normalized inputs (0 to 1).  Your `simpleComposite` isn't normalized.  Add `asFloat=True` to `simpleComposite` to get normalized values.